# Any way to send desktop notification that will prompt user to confirm yes-no?

Tags: bash, cron, notifications, user-interface, prompt

I am on Fedora 27, and have a system-on delayed (45min delay) anacrondaily job that backs up my laptop drive on a regular basis. The anacron is because my system is not always on.

The problem is that this can take a lot of memory (using [restic](https://github.com/restic/restic)), and while I am afk frequently during the work day, other times it will use a lot of memory when I am trying to work.

I am aware of `notify-send` for desktop notifications, but I'd like to be able to confirm if I want to run the anacron job when it wants to start, or delay it by another `XX minutes`, or even cancel it altogether.

Is there anyway to do this? I am not tied to `notify-send`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`zenity`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zenity). A simple example would just ask if the user wants to continue:

```
if zenity --question --text="Do you want the job to start?"
then
    echo "User accepted"
else
    echo "User rejected"
fi
```